# Is printing defaultdict supposed to be ugly (non human-readable) by default?

Tags: python

Print `dict` and `defaultdict`:

```
>>> d = {'key': 'value'}
>>> print(d)
{'key': 'value'}

>>> dd = defaultdict(lambda: 'value')
>>> dd['key']
'value'
>>> print(dd)
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7fbd44cb6b70>, {'key': 'value'})
```

With nested structure it becomes ugly:

```
>>> nested_d = {'key1': {'key2': {'key3': 'value'}}}
>>> print(nested_d)
{'key1': {'key2': {'key3': 'value'}}}

>>> def factory():
...     return defaultdict(factory)
... 
>>> nested_dd = defaultdict(factory)
>>> nested_dd['key1']['key2']['key3'] = 'value'
>>> print(nested_dd)
defaultdict(<function factory at 0x7fbd44cd4ea0>, {'key1': defaultdict(<function factory at 0x7fbd44cd4ea0>, {'key2': defaultdict(<function factory at 0x7fbd44cd4ea0>, {'key3': 'value'})})})
```

Were there any reasons for not making it human-readable by default? (UPD: I mean what are the reasons behind not having custom `__str__` defined for `defaultdict` by default?)

Comment: just call dict on it and prettyprint it if you really care about how it looks

Comment: The `repr` is really just for debugging; if you have specific formatting needs make them explicit.

Comment: I care about default behavior. Beautiful is better than ugly.

Comment: @jonrsharpe. It's not only `repr` in this case, `str()` has the same output. Might be actually worth it to take this upstream.

Comment: @DJV: there is no `__str__` method, only `__repr__`; it doesn't matter if `str()` is called here, as the fallback is used.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have `__str__` in e.g. `dir(defaultdict(list))` (on Python 2.7.12). Did I miss something?

Comment: @dhke: Sorry, the default `__str__` calls `self.__repr__()`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's quite obvious, yes. But should it? ;)

Comment: @dhke: Yes, that's the defined behaviour.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Let me formulate this differently: How far is it a POLA violation if a "builtin" type had a different `str()` and `repr()` outputs? `defaultdict` could `str()` to something more like `dict()` and `repr()` to what it has now. But we are far in opinion country, now.

Comment: @dhke: This isn't the place to discuss design decisions. Python has `__repr__` for debugging output, `__str__` for 'informal' formatted output. There is no default formatted form of any built-in container type, because Python won't dictate what the informal representation would be and expects the programmer to provide environment-appropriate output. That could mean a GUI, or a webpage, or a file, and no format will fit those all.

Comment: @dhke There already is a major "builtin" type with different `str` and `repr` outputs: `str('a') != repr('a')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`repr()` output (`defaultdict` has no `__str__`, only `__repr__`) is  *debugging output*. It is not meant to be pretty, it is meant to be *functional*. It tells you the type, the `repr()` of the callable that produces the default, and the contents.

From the [`__repr__` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__):

> This is typically used for debugging, so it is important that the representation is information-rich and unambiguous.

Like all datatypes in Python, (except for strings for obvious reasons), no informal (`__str__`) is defined because it is up to the programmer to decide what output is suitable for their use-cases. No default can be set for that, because use-cases vary so widely. Output for a file has different needs than output to a GUI or to a web-page for example.

In Python 2, convert the object to a plain dictionary first, then use `pprint()` if you want 'pretty' output:

```
def todict(d):
    if not isinstance(d, dict):
        return d
    return {k: todict(v) for k, v in d.items()}

pprint(todict(nested_dd))
```

In Python 3, `pprint` supports `defaultdict` directly:

```
>>> pprint(nested_dd)
defaultdict(<function factory at 0x105ed2f28>,
            {'key1': defaultdict(<function factory at 0x105ed2f28>,
                                 {'key2': defaultdict(<function factory at 0x105ed2f28>,
                                                      {'key3': 'value'})})})
```

Comment: I understand there are workarounds. Question is about why doesnt it print human readable text by default? It wasn't difficult to add `__str__` function, right? Were there any reasons for not having `__str__`?

Comment: @DJV: there is no human readable version of dictionaries, lists, sets or tuples either. Why would a `defaultdict` be different?

Comment: @DJV: these are *basic data structures*. There is no "human-readable" version, because it is up to the program to decide what that means.

Comment: nested dicts seem pretty readable to be, Nested defaultdicts dont. I was just wondering what benefits fo that, as it seemed to me that if `defaultdicts` were printed as `dicts` by default it would be cleaner.

Comment: @DJV: we are going round in circles here. That would loose information, the factory is a crucial piece of data on a `defaultdict` instance so is included in the `repr()`, which is meant for debugging purposes and should uniquely identify the object. From the `__repr__` documentation: *This is typically used for debugging, so it is important that the representation is information-rich and unambiguous.*

Comment: Why would it loose information if you dont remove `__repr__`, but add `__str__`? I ask what are benefits of NOT HAVING `__str__`. `__repr__` would still have this information.

Comment: @DJV: I already answered that point in the comments on your question. I don't think I'll convince you, or vice versa. Moreover, I'm the wrong person to argue this with; you should take this to the python-ideas list instead.

Comment: If you had that comment in answer (about python not dictating informal representation (any links to that?)), I'd accept the answer. :) Thanks anyway.

Comment: @DJV: it's not really part of the answer, because its not part of your question. You asked if the default output for `defaultdict` is supposed to be ugly (not human-readable) by default.

Comment: "Were there any reasons for not making it human-readable by default?" - thats the quote from queston. There is body of a question. Not just a title.

Comment: @DJV: yes, and my answer is that it is debugging output, meant to be information rich and non-ambiguous.

Comment: `print` calls `__str__`, not `__repr__`. Question is about `__str__`. I could find for another example. But I thought printing was enough for making point.

Comment: I've added a paragraph on why there is no default 'informal' `__str__` for *any* type in Python (apart from strings, them being strings already).

Comment: That paragraph is what I was looking for. Thank you. Good bye.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to know what, if anything, the author(s) were thinking or even whether they gave it much consideration at all.

For the specific case of nested `defaultdict`s, as shown your example code:

```
def factory():
    return defaultdict(factory)
nested_dd = defaultdict(factory)
nested_dd['key1']['key2']['key3'] = 'value'
```

You can avoid the issue by subclassing `dict` like this instead:

```
class Tree(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        value = self[key] = type(self)()
        return value

nested_dd = Tree()
nested_dd['key1']['key2']['key3'] = 'value'
print(nested_dd) # -> {'key1': {'key2': {'key3': 'value'}}}
```

Since the subclass doesn't define its own `__repr__()` or `__str__()` methods, instances of it will `print` (and `pprint`) just like regular `dict` instances do.

Comment: `# the benefits of defaultdict but still prints like a regular dict
class mydict(dict):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func=func
    def __missing__(self, key):
        value = self[key] = self.func()
        return value`

Comment: This class is great. No idea why this is not in the default implementation...